# ProgressDialog and AlertDialog cause leaked window

Tags: android

I have an Activity which shows a welcome message if started for the first time:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    showWelcomeMessageIfNecessary();
}

private void showWelcomeMessageIfNecessary() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Editor edit = prefs.edit();

    if (!prefs.getBoolean("welcomemessage", false)) {
        edit.putBoolean("welcomemessage", true);
        edit.commit();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.messages_welcome_content).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.errors_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }).setTitle(R.string.messages_welcome_title);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

This all works beautifully, however when I start the app, and immediately rotate the screen, I get the well-known leaked window exception.

How would I prevent this? Is there a better way to show dialogs? This also happens when I use `ProgressDialog`s in `AsyncTask`s in `Fragment`s.

Comment: may be `new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getParent());` not sure

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to cancel dialog in activity's **onStop** or **onDestroy** method. For example:

```
private AlertDialog diag = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    diag = showWelcomeMessageIfNecessary();

    if(diag != null)
        diag.show();
}

private AlertDialog showWelcomeMessageIfNecessary() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    AlertDialog alert = null;

    if (!prefs.getBoolean("welcomemessage", false)) {
        edit.putBoolean("welcomemessage", true);
        edit.commit();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.messages_welcome_content).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.errors_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        }).setTitle(R.string.messages_welcome_title);
        alert = builder.create();
    }

    return alert;
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(diag != null)
        diag.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Okay, this works. I think I get it now. If you don't dismiss the dialog `onStop()`, the dialog is still shown, attached to an old `Activity`. A bit confusing as the exception occurred at the `onShow()` line, leading me to think I leaked the window when *starting* to show the dialog.

Comment: yes, when a dialog on an activity is set to visible but somehow the activity itself is destroyed, then it causes leaked window error